# Joomla FrontEnd Editing breaks shortcodes

Tags: php, joomla, frontend, backend, shortcode

I have a joomla website in localhost.

I installed a template called Helix 2 which also has a set of Shortcodes. (i just put in something like [block]blah blah [/block] and my blah blah is highlighted in a nice looking box.)

I posted beautiful looking articles that way from BackEnd.  Unfortunately, I have setup some users to be able to edit those articles from frontend.  I have manually checked the Database and the shortcode is saved in the database.  But when clicking edit in frontend, THAT DATABASE VERSION is not loaded in the edit field!  When editing from frontend, the joomla engine DOESNOT load the database version of the article, but the version rendered from the browser or something else.  The latter version doesn't have the shortcodes.  So, after clicking save from Frontend the original article formatting is lost!  I then have to  manually reenter shortcodes in the frontend.

So the solution is, while clicking on edit button, if the article for editing is loaded from the database I can see my shortcodes in their proper places.  So, is there a setting anywhere in joomla that can help me out with this?

PS: I HAVE TRIED ALL EDITORS TINYMCE, JCE, EDITOR-NONE WITH SAME RESULTS.  ITS NOT THE EDITOR PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

Which Joomla version are you using?

In Joomla 2.5 if you use a user from a different group, checkout the text filter options tab in the general settings. If you login as a super-admin and the setting for that group is "No filter", please try to change to "default blacklist" than save. Clear all joomla cache (just to be on the save site). Than change back to "No filter" option.

I have seen complaints on the joomla forum that the No Filter option while default set in some cases is not properely set. Resetting it to default blacklist and back to "No filter" might solve that problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work.

The only difference is that now, the full browser version of the article is loaded without any loss in formatting.  But the Shortcodes [] are still missing.  I want my users to see the shortcode so that they can edit it instead of a lengthy sequence of <div> tags.

Strangely the shortcodes are saved  in the DB with the article!

Answer (score 0):

What a simple solution and I had to spend so many sleepless nights surfing for a solution. In my site [http://lokkatha.com](http://lokkatha.com/150)the problem was persisting for quite some time. However, with the help of the solution suggested by Wouter here, I could sort it out. the process is

Go to BACKEND ADMIN >> General configuration >> Text filters

Covert all filters to NO FILTERING The problem is solved.